# Laravel hasMany Relation not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 master table

1. tbl_master_delivery_type
2. tbl_master_business_types

and 2 user table

1. tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options
2. tbl_users_business

### tbl_master_delivery_type tables - master tables

```
delivery_type_id (primary key)
delivery_type_name
created_by
updated_by
is_delete
status
deleted_at
created_at
updated_at
```

### tbl_master_business_types - master tables

```
business_type_id (primary key)
business_type_name
description
created_by
updated_by
is_delete
status
deleted_at
created_at
updated_at
```

### tbl_users_business - user table

```
business_id (primary key)
```

### tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options - user table

```
business_del_sub_option_id (primary key)
business_id (foreign key)
business_type_id (foreign key)
delivery_type_id (foreign key
deleted_at
created_at
updated_at
```

So I want to get data from `tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options` table using relationship in laravel.
I have tried using hasMany relationship in function some as below code.

```php
public function usersBusinessDeliveryTypesWeb()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UsersBusinessSubDeliveryOption', 'business_id');
}
```

but I am getting the null value.

```php
[usersBusinessDeliveryTypesWeb] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
                (

                )

    )
```

But if I make the function using belongsTo.

```php
public function usersBusinessDeliveryTypesWeb()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UsersBusinessSubDeliveryOption', 'business_id');
}
```

then I am getting only one value as given below.

```php
[usersBusinessDeliveryTypesWeb] => App\UsersBusinessSubDeliveryOption Object
(
    [primaryKey:protected] => business_del_sub_option_id
    [table:protected] => tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => business_id
            [1] => business_type_id
            [2] => delivery_type_id
        )
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [dates] => Array
        (
            [0] => deleted_at
        )
    [connection:protected] => pgsql
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] =>
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [business_del_sub_option_id] => 1
            [business_id] => 4
            [business_type_id] => 3
            [delivery_type_id] => 1
            [deleted_at] =>
            [created_at] =>
            [updated_at] =>
        )
    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [business_del_sub_option_id] => 1
            [business_id] => 4
            [business_type_id] => 3
            [delivery_type_id] => 1
            [deleted_at] =>
            [created_at] =>
            [updated_at] =>
        )
    [changes:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [casts:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [dateFormat:protected] =>
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [observables:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [relations:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [touches:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [timestamps] => 1
    [visible:protected] => Array
        (

        )
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )
    [forceDeleting:protected] =>
)
```

But actually I want the output like this.

```php
[usersBusinessDeliveryTypesWeb] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\UsersBusinessSubDeliveryOption Object
                (
                    [primaryKey:protected] => business_del_sub_option_id
                    [table:protected] => tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options
                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => business_id
                            [1] => business_type_id
                            [2] => delivery_type_id
                        )
                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [dates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => deleted_at
                        )
                    [connection:protected] => pgsql
                    [keyType:protected] => int
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [withCount:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [exists] => 1
                    [wasRecentlyCreated] =>
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [business_del_sub_option_id] => 1
                            [business_id] => 4
                            [business_type_id] => 3
                            [delivery_type_id] => 1
                            [deleted_at] =>
                            [created_at] =>
                            [updated_at] =>
                        )
                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [business_del_sub_option_id] => 1
                            [business_id] => 4
                            [business_type_id] => 3
                            [delivery_type_id] => 1
                            [deleted_at] =>
                            [created_at] =>
                            [updated_at] =>
                        )
                    [changes:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [dateFormat:protected] =>
                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )
                    [forceDeleting:protected] =>
                )
            [1] => App\UsersBusinessSubDeliveryOption Object
                (
                    [primaryKey:protected] => business_del_sub_option_id
                    [table:protected] => tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options
                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => business_id
                            [1] => business_type_id
                            [2] => delivery_type_id
                        )
                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [dates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => deleted_at
                        )
                    [connection:protected] => pgsql
                    [keyType:protected] => int
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [withCount:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [exists] => 1
                    [wasRecentlyCreated] =>
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [business_del_sub_option_id] => 1
                            [business_id] => 4
                            [business_type_id] => 3
                            [delivery_type_id] => 2
                            [deleted_at] =>
                            [created_at] =>
                            [updated_at] =>
                        )
                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [business_del_sub_option_id] => 1
                            [business_id] => 4
                            [business_type_id] => 3
                            [delivery_type_id] => 2
                            [deleted_at] =>
                            [created_at] =>
                            [updated_at] =>
                        )
                    [changes:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [dateFormat:protected] =>
                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (

                        )
                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )
                    [forceDeleting:protected] =>
                )
)
```

Comment: make sure to add the inverse too likr  **tbl_users_business** -> hasMany sub_delivery_options and **tbl_users_business_sub_delivery_options**  -> belongsTo tbl_users_business

Comment: Have you specified the table property in both models?

Answer (score 0):

```
hasOne -> returns one item

hasMany -> returns a collection

belongsTo -> returns one item

belongsToMany -> returns a collection. (works only with pivot tables)
```

Also, in your models, do you specify your primary key, cause you are not using the standard 'id' col for each table... instead you use names like: delivery_type_id.

i would, either Check that my models have the proper id set.
Or Use explicitly 
`return $this->hasMany('App\UsersBusinessSubDeliveryOption', 'business_id', 'business_id');`